# Reference Custom Field in Workfront Collection

Tags: report, attask, workfront-api

I have a project report in Workfront where I am trying to reference custom fields defined on a Workfront task.  In the example below, both "Custom Flag" and "Num Devices" are custom fields on Tasks.

```
displayname=Test
listdelimiter=&#xfeff;
listmethod=nested(tasks).lists
textmode=true
type=iterate
valueexpression=IF({DE:Custom Flag}="Implementation",{DE:Num Devices},"")
valueformat=HTML
```

I have no problem referencing Workfront's packaged "tasks" fields in the manner specified above, but any time I try this with a custom field, the column ends up blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are referencing another Object your Custom data Syntax is incorrect it should be.

```
 displayname=Test
 listdelimiter=&#xfeff;
 listmethod=nested(tasks).lists
 textmode=true
 type=iterate
 valueexpression=IF({DE:tasks:Custom Flag}="Implementation",{DE:tasks:Num Devices},"")
 valueformat=HTML
```

if you do not specify tasks in the calculation it is looking for the custom element on the report object in this case Project.

Comment: Thanks so much, Michael!  That's exactly what I need.  I think I hit on everything surrounding your example, but never quite got it exactly.  I appreciate your help!